# Detect changes of all textbox values

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a form with alot of textboxes, and I have a function that I want to run when a value in any of the textboxes is changed. Is there a way to do the same thing for every textbox without duplicating the code for each and every textbox?  Here's the code that works for one:

```
private void Team1Q2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int parsedValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(Team1Q1.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
        Team1Q1.Text = "0";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        CalculateTotals();
    }
}
```

Comment: open your form's designer.cs, you can see the event handler mappings. You need to edit this file to bind the same event handler function for all your textbox controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register this event handler for all of your `textboxes`, and cast the `sender` object to use the event raiser textbox.

**Code:**

```
private void Team1Q2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox senderTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    int parsedValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(senderTextBox.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
        senderTextBox.Text = "0";
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        CalculateTotals();
    }
}
```

**Subscribing event handler:**

```
txtbox1.TextChanged += Team1Q2_TextChanged;
txtbox2.TextChanged += Team1Q2_TextChanged;
txtbox3.TextChanged += Team1Q2_TextChanged;
//so on
```

Comment: literally added just 1 line to my loop in my Form_Load function `  tbox.TextChanged += Team1Q1_TextChanged;`

Comment: Have one more problem though I am trying to send the totals (or one value for each team over to another form. i cannot figure out how to do that

Comment: @BeauAltman Ask another question with all the details. Because it doesn't belong to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just set all the `TextChanged` events for your TextBoxes to `Team1Q2_TextChanged` in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Team1Q2_TextChanged is just an event handler you created for one of the textboxes. You can use the same event handler for all the textboxes. You will have to set all the textboxes's changed events to the same event handler.

If you are setting up the eventhandlers in visual studio designer, just copy paste the same event handler for all.

If you are setting up the event handlers in C# code behind, you can do this

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
textBox3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
```

If you see I am using the same event handler for all textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

in `Form_load`, assign the `text_changed` event to all textboxes

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        (item as TextBox).TextChanged += Form6_TextChanged;
}
```

and then you can handle the all `text_changed` event

```
void Form6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox T = sender as TextBox;
    //this is your detail
}
```

Comment: Using `typeof()` is better than work with type name, so you can use  `if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
private void TextBoxEventHandler_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var entryField = sender as TextBox;

   lblKeyedValue.Text = entryField.Text.ToUpper();
}
```

and Add this event handler into textbox(s) like below...

```
yourTextBoxName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextBoxEventHandler_TextChanged);
```